# Join two array column in squence - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a data frame with two Array column, trying to create a new column by joining both A and B sequentially.

```
val df = Seq((Seq("a","b","c"),Seq("d","5","6"))).toDF("A","B")
```

Expected output:

C: ["a d", "b 5", "c 6"]

I am exploring both the arrays and join it again using "import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array" function but it's not giving expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the expected result using the arrays_zip function as like below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.arrays_zip
val output = df.withColumn(
 "zipped", arrays_zip($"A", $"B")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Spark not have ready function for it. You can use user defined function here `zip` for example:

```
import spark.implicits._
def zipFunc: (Seq[String], Seq[String]) => Seq[String] = (x: Seq[String], y: Seq[String]) => 
  x.zip(y).map{ case (xi, yi) => s"$xi $yi"}

val df = Seq(
  (Seq("a","b","c"), Seq("d","5","6"))
).toDF("A","B")
df.printSchema()
val zipUDF = spark.udf.register("zipUdf", zipFunc)
df.withColumn("C", zipUDF($"A", $"B")).show()
```

prints:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+
|        A|        B|              C|
+---------+---------+---------------+
|[a, b, c]|[d, 5, 6]|[a d, b 5, c 6]|
+---------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: it is working well in the example, but when I replace the columns of my table I am getting a Task not serializable error

Comment: @VSr I updated answer, but your decision is better.